# Store data from columns of a text file to an array. in C

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Process Priority    Burst   Arrival
1   8   15  0
2   3   20  0
3   4   20  20
4   4   20  25
5   5   5   45
6   5   15  55
7   9   10  70
8   6   15  100
9   5   15  105
10  5   15  115
```

The columns are separated by tabs.
I need to ignore the first line and then all entries from one column store them into an array such as "int process[10]".

I have found this thread :[Reading in a specific column of data from a text file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345698/reading-in-a-specific-column-of-data-from-a-text-file-in-c) , however the way is done is very specific to the way the data is set up in the op's question.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. This grabs all columns you have from the file and is compliant with **ansi**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void parseLine(char *line, int *num1, int *num2, int *num3, int *num4 ){

    char* temp;

    temp = strchr(line,'\t');
    temp[0] = '\0';
    *num1 = atoi(line);
    line = temp + 1;

    temp = strchr(line, '\t');
    temp[0] = '\0';
    *num2 = atoi(line);
    line = temp + 1;

    temp = strchr(line, '\t');
    temp[0] = '\0';
    *num3 = atoi(line);
    line = temp + 1;

    *num4 = atoi(line);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char line[100];
    
    int process[10];
    int priority[10];
    int burst[10];
    int arrival[10];
    int i;
    int j;

    i = 0;

    if ((fp = fopen("./yourfile.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Opening File\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);


    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        parseLine(line, &process[i],&priority[i],&burst[i],&arrival[i]);
        i++;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        printf("Process: %d, Priority: %d, Burst: %d, Arrival: %d\n", process[j], priority[j], burst[j], arrival[j]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My bad, was kind of speed coding didn't realize the subtle mistake there, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: sorry I didn't see this, thank you this is definitely in accordance with the rest of my code.

Answer (score 0):

First a note on this, is not a complete solution but I think it will help you with the parsing of the file. Also instead of

> store them into an array such as "int process[10]"

I think it would better to store them on a **dynamic array**, otherwise you would need to know, before hand, the numbers of line of the column, that you are trying to extract. This code only parse the file given your format and print the values of the first column, I think can be adapted to your situation after you implement the dynamic array so here it is:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*scan_file: read each of the lines of the file.*/
int scan_file(char *filename)
{
    char *line_buf = NULL;
    size_t line_buf_size = 0;
    ssize_t line_size;
    char *next = NULL;

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file '%s'\n", filename);
        return 1;
    } 
    /*Get the first line of the file and do nothing with it*/
    line_size = getline(&line_buf, &line_buf_size, fp);
    while (line_size > 0)
    {
        //second and subsecuent lines
        line_size = getline(&line_buf, &line_buf_size,fp);
        if (line_size <= 0)
            break;
        line_buf[line_size-1] = '\0'; /*removing '\n' */
        char *part = strtok_r(line_buf, "    ", &next);
        if (part)
            printf("NUMBER: %s\n", part);
    }

    // don't forget to free the line_buf used by getline
    free(line_buf);
    line_buf = NULL;
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{
    scan_file("file.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** Here I assume that the file is called `file.txt` you should change it for the name of your file.

**OUTPUT:**

```
NUMBER: 1
NUMBER: 2
NUMBER: 3
NUMBER: 4
NUMBER: 5
NUMBER: 6
NUMBER: 7
NUMBER: 8
NUMBER: 9
NUMBER: 10
```

I put it in this way so you could identify the line `printf("NUMBER: %s\n", part);`, here you could change it to something that push this value into the dynamic array.

Comment: Oh thank you, yeah I know the limit since it;s actually all I post it (pretty short) , thank you I will implement this.

Comment: A line might not end with a `'\n'`  (perhaps last line in input) making `line_buf[line_size-1] = '\0';` incorrect.